# How to remove the title bar in mintty cygwin

Tags: cygwin, mintty

How do i remove the title bar in the cygwin mintty terminal window ? 
there is no option in the options -> window configuration

[image]

Comment: That title bar is part of the standard Windows window decoration. When you remove it, you also remove the ability to move, minimize, maximize, and close the window and to open the system menu.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be using *mintty*'s ***-B*** (***--Border***) option when invoking it. Check [[GitHub.Mintty]: mintty](https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html) (or `man mintty`) for more details.

As a note, on my (*Win 10*) machine *mintty*'s window quickly disappears, when specifying the option.

Comment: where is the best way to configure it ? so it will be permanent ?

Comment: Most likely you launch it from *Win* typically via a shortcut. If so, modify the shortcut to include this option.

Comment: In the current version, `-B` requires an argument, `frame` or `void`.  `void` makes it very difficult to move around and resize (`Ctrl-Alt-Drag` doesn't seem to work for me, Win10), but `frame` at least retains the `WinKey+<Arrow>` buttons to move and resize along the edges.  You still get a few-pixel-tall sliver of a title bar unless you make it totally full-screen.  If using `void`, also check out the `-w` and `--geometry` options to set the initial position and size of the window, respectively.